# Hidden redirect code

Tags: file, web, redirect

My website uses Matrix Stats for analysis http://matrixstats.walkingenglishman.com/ and on analysis I found a file /images/dfuwCE369.php which is much accessed. I have been told the file is a hack redirect script but I cannot find it and nor can my host provider.It continues to elude detection so I can remove it. Any clues would help tremendously. Thank you.

[image]